# Jquery back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

(sorry for my bad English)
I checked all posts about Jquery back button here and for some reason nothing worked with me so please help me...

I simply want when I run Jquery function by clicking on a link with hash, the browser will shows me the back button.
When I click the back button I want it to run the previous function.

here are the codes...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //jQuery v1.10.2
</head>
<body>


<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<div id="prodmenu">
  <a href="#link1" id="link1" class="gat">Link1</a>
  <a href="#link2" id="link2" class="gat">Link2</a>
</div>

<script>

$("#link1").click(function() { 
$("#div1").fadeOut(); 
$("#div2").animate({top:'500px'},"slow");
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by "the browser will shows me the back button"?

Comment: Sorry for my english again, I meant the browser back button will be active.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange) for the #hash history.

Here is an [example](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test2).